# For what reason(s), one may introduce the axiom of finite limits when they are already implied (?) by other axioms?

Tags: category-theory

I've been reading Lawvere's "Sets for Mathematics". In it on page 73, it is taken as an axiom that *finite limits exist in $S$* (Where $S$ is the category of sets and functions).

I'm confused as to how to interpret the axiom. Is it an additional axiom on top of following axioms (already introduced):

1. There exists a terminal object 1.
2. There exists an initial object 0.
3. 1 is a separator.
4. $1\ncong 0$.
5. There exists a sum for any pair of objects $A,B$.
6. There exists a product for any pair of objects $A,B$.
7. $(1+1)$ is truth value object together with the property that any function into it is a characteristic function of a unique (up to
   equivalence) part.

Or, is it intended as a replacement for axioms 1 and 6?

I don't see how latter can be the case if we are to interpret "data" of a limit not as a functor viewed as a diagram but as an I-indexed family of Sets and J-indexed family of maps (I, J are sets) which are compatible with the data type $d,c:J\rightarrow I$ (By compatible I mean $A_{dj}$ is the domain of $f_j$ and $A_{cj}$ is the codomain of $f_j$), because then due to replacement of previous axioms, in the beginning there would be no set guaranteed in order to serve as indexing set (which becomes especially true, when the axiom of finite colimits is introduced). Furthermore, I don't see the need for this axiom, as finite limits can be computed using finite binary products and equalizers.

PS:

1. Up until this point in the book, the only notion of finite set introduced is that of Dedekind-finiteness. Interpreting finite set to mean Dedekind-finite, I wonder: could the existence of finite limits be deduced?

Comment: Which of the 7 axioms implies the existence of equalizers ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Using the contravariant functoriality of preimages, and characteristic functions, one is able to construct inverse images of any part along any map. Then, given a pair of parallel functions $f_0, f_1:A\rightarrow B$, their equalizer is the inverse image of the diagonal map $\delta_B:B\hookrightarrow B\times B$ along $\langle f_0, f_1\rangle :A\rightarrow B\times B$. I can try to provide more detail, just let me know.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the definitions used in 7. If you use good/strong definitions then, yes, you get pullbacks of monomorphisms, which together with binary products gives you equalisers.

Comment: @ZhenLin That is exactly the case with the description of $S$ presented in the book.